# Android, Download a .txt file and save internally

Tags: java, android, file, download

like the title states i am simply trying to download a test.txt file, the following url and save it internally, ideally within drawable.

i have been trying to modify this to work but will little success i keep getting "unable to download null" errors

```
int count;          
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.darkliteempire.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/testdownload.txt");
    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
    conexion.connect();
    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download");

    if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
        testDirectory.mkdir();
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory + "/test.txt");
    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;
    int progress = 0;

    while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;

        int progress_temp = (int) total * 100 / lenghtOfFile;

        fos.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    is.close();
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR DOWNLOADING", "Unable to download" + e.getMessage());
}
```

There must be a simpler way to do this?
the file itself is tiny with perhaps 3 or 4 lines of text so i dont need anything fancy

Comment: your URL is wrong "https: / / www.http : / / dark..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [AQuery library](http://code.google.com/p/android-query) you get something pretty straightforward. Plus you'll get hips of other cool functions to shorten your code.

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI

```
String url = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/featured?max-results=16";             

File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File target = new File(ext, "aquery/myfolder/photos.xml");              
aq.progress(R.id.progress).download(url, target, new AjaxCallback<File>(){            
        public void callback(String url, File file, AjaxStatus status) {                    
                if(file != null){
                        showResult("File:" + file.length() + ":" + file, status);
                }else{
                        showResult("Failed", status);
                }
        }            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Update your below code line and write valid url.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.http://darkliteempire.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/testdownload.txt");
```

after write valid url your code line look like this.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.darkliteempire.gaming.multiplay.co.uk/testdownload.txt");
```

it will solve your problem.

Comment: yea i noticed the error after putting it up here, i corrected it and i still have the same problem